# How can I retrieve two or more field from a DataTable using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following line of code

```
List<String> rsSIDs = dtPermissions.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                   .Select(dr => dr.Field<String>("WindowsSID"))
                                   .ToList();
```

How do I edit this line of code so that it can contain multiple fields in the resulting list?

Comment: Use two `Field` calls in an anonymous type, eg `Select( dr=>new {someField=dr.Field..., otherField=dr...})`.

Comment: I normally use : dtPermissions.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { id = x.Field<string>("Windows"), name = x.Field<string>("Name")}).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<DtoObject> rsSIDs = dtPermissions.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                   .Select(dr =>   new DtoObject()
        { WindowsSID = dr.Field<String>("WindowsSID") , UserName = dt.Field<String>("UserName")})
                                   .ToList();


public class DtoObject
    {
        public string WindowsSID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```